# onPress not working in menu for ios devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I want to mention that this problem only occurs on ios devices android just works fine.

I have menu userMenu class

```
 import Menu, {MenuItem, MenuDivider} from 'react-native-material-menu';

 class UserMenu extends React.Component {      

        logout() {
            this.props.logout().then(() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth')
            })
        }        

        render() {

            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Menu
                        ref={ref => this._menu = ref}
                        button={
                            <Text
                                style={{padding: 15}}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    this._menu.show()
                                }}>
                                <FontAwesome5 name={'caret-down'} color={'#fff'} size={25}/>
                            </Text>
                        }
                    >
                        <MenuItem disabled={true}>{this.props.auth.user.customer.name}</MenuItem>
                        <MenuDivider/>
                        <MenuItem
                            onPress={() => {
                                this._customerProfile.show();
                                this._menu.hide();
                            }}>
                            <FontAwesome5 name={'cog'}/> Settings
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem
                            onPress={this.logout.bind(this)}>
                            <FontAwesome5 name={'sign-out-alt'}/> Logout
                        </MenuItem>
                    </Menu>

                    <CustomerProfile
                        onRef={ref => this._customerProfile = ref}
                    />
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        }

    };
```

if i clicked settings in menu it call `this._customerProfile.show()` also `this._menu.hide()` menu hide works but customerProfile not showing up. If i take menu item outside of Menu it works customerProfile shows.

Any idea what can cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use TouchableOpacity

```
renderButton: function() {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}>
      <Image
        style={styles.button}
        source={require('./myButton.png')}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
},
```

Link for [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html)

Comment: MenuItem component use TouchableOpacity and onPress is called i press it. the problem is that is not working in Menu component. I just tried  when i replace Menu component with View it works. it works also when i place `MenuItem` outside of `Menu` component